# Implementing in C - Advent of code 2018: Day 1_2

Tags: c

This is the problem:

> You notice that the device repeats the same frequency change list over
>   and over. To calibrate the device, you need to find the first
>   frequency it reaches twice.
>
> For example, using the same list of changes above, the device would
>   loop as follows:
>
> - Current frequency 0, change of +1; resulting frequency 1.
> - Current frequency 1, change of -2; resulting frequency -1.
> - Current frequency -1, change of +3; resulting frequency 2.
> - Current frequency 2, change of +1; resulting frequency 3.
> - (At this point, the device continues from the start of the list.)
> - Current frequency 3, change of +1; resulting frequency 4.
> - Current frequency 4, change of -2; resulting frequency 2, which has already been seen.
>
> In this example, the first frequency reached twice is 2. Note that
>   your device might need to repeat its list of frequency changes many
>   times before a duplicate frequency is found, and that duplicates might
>   be found while in the middle of processing the list.
>
> Here are other examples:
>
> - +1, -1 first reaches 0 twice.
> - +3, +3, +4, -2, -4 first reaches 10 twice.
> - -6, +3, +8, +5, -6 first reaches 5 twice.
> - +7, +7, -2, -7, -4 first reaches 14 twice.
>
> What is the first frequency your device reaches twice?

Here is my implementation in C which loops through the whole list but never finds a match.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void){

    int sum = 0;
    int q = 0;
    int len = 0;
    char buffer[20];
    int val = 0;
    int list[2000];
    int *plist = list;

    FILE *pFile = NULL;
    pFile = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (pFile == NULL){
        printf("file failed to open\n");
        return -1;
    }

    while((fgets(buffer, 20, pFile)) != NULL){  //store all the sums (calculated frequncies induced by changes) in an array called list
        sum += atoi(buffer);
        *plist = sum;
        ++plist;
        ++len;
        }

    fclose(pFile);
    pFile = NULL;
    plist = list;

    printf("length is %d\n\n", len);

    //below will now iterate through the loop and treat it as circular, so up to the element before current element 

    for(int i = 0; i < len && val == 0; ++i){
        for(int j = i + 1; j < len + i; ++j){
            if (j >= len)
                q = abs(len - j);
            else
                q = j;
            printf("here is i: %d\there is j: %d\n", list[i], list[q]);
            if(list[i] == list[q]){
                val = list[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("the first frequency is %d\n", val);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try using a debugger.

Comment: I've debugged the hell out of this thing

Comment: I also realize that the absolute val method can be replaced by a mod operator and reduced to one line, but this works too.

Comment: If you've tried a debugger, have you tried adding more `printf` statements to be sure you're properly computing whatever it is you're trying to compute? This is just problem solving. Narrow down the probable causes.

Comment: For some sample input (specified that you show) that cause your problem to fail, what is the actual output you get? What is the expected output?

Comment: What is the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code. Most importantly, you only iterate through the list of frequency changes once, while even the task description mentions that you might need to do it multiple times. A solution is to read the changes file into an array and then create 2nd array with sums (as you do it now), by applying 1st one a few times starting from initial frequency = 0. Also, the sum array after initialisation should be inserted 0 element at the beginning, which is the starting frequency.

I do not know your input file format, so you need to check that it is read as expected. However, I tested the 2nd part of your code (the double loop) with `list` array initialised to both +1, -1 and +3, +3, +4, -2, -4 sum sequences (with the latter repeated twice), and it worked fine.

Two other changes to consider:

- Do not use `val == 0` as loop stop condition; if 0 is the repeated value, the loop will iterate through all elements. Instead, consider using a flag (e.g. Boolean variable) to exit both inner and outer loops.
- There is no need to "treat loop as circular", it is enough to compare current element with all future elements.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I understand now the true requirements for the problem. I will think of a way to implement it properly now. One point I don't understand from your comments though, is why is the "0" not a good way to go for the outer loop exit condition? Isn't using a Boolean flag essentially the same thing? Here I tell the loop "if val == 0, don't execute the loop. if it is == 0, then keep going. What does it matter whether its 0/1 or true/false. Isn't the bool type ultimately just int type with a value of 1 or 0?

Comment: You are right about there being no difference between 0/1 and true/false. The issue here is that val is also used as the variable to store the repeated frequency. Take +1, -1 series: your code will correctly identify 0 as repeated frequency, however because val was initially also 0, it will not exit the loop - thus it only works if repeated frequency != 0. If you create separate int, name it e.g.  ExitLoop and use this as the flag - all will be fine.